# Live radio streaming using URL in iOS

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer, avplayer, tunein

I have to stream live radio.Stream comes from tuneins URL. Can anyone suggest how I can stream for this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use AVPlayer to play stream live radio.